# How to add RBAC in Azure Databricks using ARM

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-databricks

I am trying to add RBAC in Azure Databricks using ARM. I have managed to add RBAC using ARM in App Insights with the following code

```
"resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components/providers/roleAssignments",
      "apiVersion": "2017-05-01",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('AppInsightName'),'/Microsoft.Authorization/',guid('AppInsightName'))]",
      "properties": {
        "roleDefinitionId": "[variables(parameters('builtInRoleType'))]",
        "principalId": "[parameters('principalId')]"
      }
    }
  ]
```

Looking for some input in creating RBAC in Databricks using ARM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'd use the exact same approach:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces/providers/roleAssignments",
  "apiVersion": "2017-05-01",
  "name": "[concat(parameters('databricks_name'),'/Microsoft.Authorization/',guid('something'))]",
  "properties": {
    "roleDefinitionId": "[variables(parameters('builtInRoleType'))]",
    "principalId": "[parameters('principalId')]"
  }
}
```